# Python encoded string corrupts when retrieving from list

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

I have the following list:

```
adrList = {0: ['Belgium'], 1: ["Fontaine l'Ev\\xc3\\xaaque"]}
print adrList
```

The adrList prints correctly:

```
{0: ['Belgium'], 1: ["Fontaine l'Ev\\xc3\\xaaque"]}
```

However, when I retrieve the encoded value from position 1:

```
city =  adrList[1][0]
print city
```

I get the following result:

```
Fontaine L'ev\xe3\xaaque
```

As you can see, the two double backslashes change to regular backslashes, the 'xc3' changes to 'xe3', and some of the uppercase/lowercase characters change.

After retrieving the value the encoding is corrupted, and performing an action such as json.dumps() on it will crash. Why does it change, and how do I retrieve the value literally without it being altered?

Edit: Found the source of my problem: string.capwords was being run on the value inside the setter of the property I was trying to assign this value to, which messed up the encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.7.6, I don't see similar problems on my side:

```
>>> adrList = {0: ['Belgium'], 1: ["Fontaine l'Ev\\xc3\\xaaque"]}
>>> print adrList
{0: ['Belgium'], 1: ["Fontaine l'Ev\\xc3\\xaaque"]}
>>> city =  adrList[1][0]
>>> print city
Fontaine l'Ev\xc3\xaaque
```

The double backslashes are gone (what else did you expect from `print`), but everything else stays in place, there's no `xc3` changing to `xe3` or whatever.

Moreover, I think you don't actually need double slashes, it works more correctly then:

```
>>> adrList = {0: ['Belgium'], 1: ["Fontaine l'Ev\xc3\xaaque"]}
>>> print adrList
{0: ['Belgium'], 1: ["Fontaine l'Ev\xc3\xaaque"]}
>>> city =  adrList[1][0]
>>> print city
Fontaine l'Evêque
>>>
```

Comment: Yes, the strange thing is that the example I gave behaves slightly different from my actual code. In my code I retrieve this string from a PostgreSQL DB, using a connector with UTF-8 encoding. When I print the object, I get the exact output I gave for adrList (with double backslashes instead of single). When I enter the example hardcoded, it only removes the backslash and doesn't change the 'xc3' to 'xe3' like it does with the actual object. I'm not sure what the difference could be between the two, because when I print my actual object and the hardcoded one, they are 100% the same..

Comment: The fact that it also messes with the capitalization when I retrieve it makes me think some kind of conversion is taking place, but I can't find anything on what could be causing it. All I'm doing is retrieving a value from a list inside an object..

Answer (score 0):

Found the source of the error: string.capwords was being run on the setter of the property I was trying to assign this value to, which messed up the encoding. That explains the difference with the example code I posted originally..